# How to change which variable is used, depending on another value

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, echo

I'm trying to make a fun side project and have come to a stop on a small problem. I am trying to have the echo command placed inside of the while and mysqli_fetch_assoc command as the data changes everytime the page refreshes, from the select from table random function.

I select random items like this:

```
$survivor_set = random_survivor();
$item_set = random_item();
$firstaidkitaddon_set = random_firstaidkitaddon();
$flashlightaddon_set = random_flashlightaddon();
$keyaddon_set = random_keyaddon();
$mapaddon_set = random_mapaddon();
$toolboxaddon_set = random_toolboxaddon();
$survivoroffering_set = random_survivoroffering();
```

The problem line of code looks like this:

```
<?php while($toolboxaddon = mysqli_fetch_assoc($toolboxaddon_set)) { ?>
```

However I need the words after `$` to be changed so was looking for something like this to work:

```
<?php while($ echo h($item['item']);addon = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ echo h($item['type']);addon_set)) { ?>
```

This is probably explained poorly, I would appreciate if anyone could lend some time to help me where I can show in more details what exactly I am trying to accomplish.

The code shows the random item that was selected from the table.

```
<?php while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($item_set)) { ?> 
  <?php echo h($item['name']);?> E.g. Engineers Toolbox 
  <?php echo h($item['rarity']);?> E.g. veryrare 
  <?php echo h($item['type']);?> E.g. toolbox 
  <?php echo h($item['media']);?> E.g. engineerstoolbox.png 
<?php } ?>
```

I am then trying to find a way to put the `echo h($item['type'])` into the next output. so it would look like this when it is a toolbox.

`<?php while($toolbox = mysqli_fetch_assoc($toolbox_set)) { ?>`

But then could change due to it being a different item type that was pulled:

`<?php while($flashlight = mysqli_fetch_assoc($flashlight_set)) { ?>`

Full code, for context: https://zerobin.net/?9f772676aa87df3f#Gxy43WGqShTkL/VG42+t3nT4+sxGhxFy+GDB0B3+YH0=

Comment: Your second bit if code makes no sense at all, so it's difficult to see what you're trying to achieve from that. `I need the words after $ to be changed` is also unclear - can you give a better description and example of what precisely you mean?

Comment: I am trying to find a way to have the words after $ changed to the value that was selected from a table.


`<?php while($toolboxaddon = mysqli_fetch_assoc($toolboxaddon_set)) { ?>
     
<?php } ?>
        
<?php mysqli_free_result($toolboxaddon_set);?>`

Is there a way in which I can have the echo command inside where $toolboxaddon is? 

I have created a file paste to show the entire code. 
https://zerobin.net/?9f772676aa87df3f#Gxy43WGqShTkL/VG42+t3nT4+sxGhxFy+GDB0B3+YH0=

Comment: Echo is for outputting to the screen. It has nothing to do with changing values. Still don't know what you mean by the "words after $" either. What words? Let's try it another way - show us what data is coming from `$toolboxaddon_set` and what output you want to get when the code has finished.

Comment: Do you simply want to output all the values from `$toolboxaddon_set` onto the screen?

Comment: This code shows the random item that was selected from the table.

`<?php while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($item_set)) { ?>`
`<?php echo h($item['name']);?>` E.g. Engineers Toolbox
`<?php echo h($item['rarity']);?>` E.g. veryrare
`<?php echo h($item['type']);?>` E.g. toolbox
`<?php echo h($item['media']);?>` E.g. engineerstoolbox.png
`<?php } ?>`

I am then trying to find a way to put the `echo h($item['type'])` into the next output. so it would look like this when it is a toolbox. 

`<?php while($toolbox = mysqli_fetch_assoc($toolbox_set)) { ?>`

Comment: But then could change due to it being a different item type that was pulled;

`<?php while($flashlight = mysqli_fetch_assoc($flashlight_set)) { ?>`

Comment: Ok I think I understand better now - see answer below, I'm pretty sure that's what you're after.

Comment: was the answer below useful to you?

Answer (score 0):

You should store all your different add-on results in an [associative array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) where the keys match the possible "type" values from your main item query. This allows you to select an item from the array using a string to reference its key - and you can take that string value from your `$item['type']` variable.

e.g.

```
$survivor_set = random_survivor();
$item_set = random_item();

$addons = array(
  "firstaid" => random_firstaidkitaddon(),
  "flashlight" => = random_flashlightaddon(),
  "key" = random_keyaddon(),
  "map" = random_mapaddon(),
  "toolbox" => random_toolboxaddon()
);

$survivoroffering_set = random_survivoroffering();
```

Then later on you can select the right set of results from the associative array by selecting the index which matches `$item['type']`:

```
<div class="itemaddonscontainer">
  <div class="<?php echo h($item['type']);?>">
    <?php while($addon = mysqli_fetch_assoc($addons[$item['type']])) { ?>
      <img class="<?php echo h($addon['rarity']);?> survivor-item" src="imgs/survivor/itemaddon/<?php echo h($addon['media']);?>"/>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

N.B. `mysqli_free_result` probably isn't necessary here.

Comment: `mysqli_free_result()` is probably never necessary. :)